# Python data connection OLAP/Cube

Tags: python, data-connections

I would like to connect the OLAP Cube through python.

- (First)Basically I would like to import data from OLAP Cube.
- (Second)And import columns through DAX is there any way to run DAX formula in Python.

I'm ok if python doesn't have any option for DAX. However at least I would like to import data from OLAP Cube.

Please assist me with the code or guide me. Let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cubes.  Cubes is a light-weight Python framework and set of tools for development of reporting and analytical applications, Online Analytical Processing (OLAP), multidimensional analysis and browsing of aggregated data.